# Random error during installation game created by Inno setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, istool

Hi when I use instalation that will install game it is OK. But sometime I will get this error:

> C\game\ Scared2\pad\graphics02,zip  An error occurred while trying to
>   copy a file: the suource file is corrupted.

It can be different file. But always it is big file.

Here is my script:

```
[Setup]
InternalCompressLevel=ultra64
OutputDir=C:\SA
OutputBaseFilename=Instalace
VersionInfoVersion=2.65.1
VersionInfoCompany=Ascaron
Compression=lzma/ultra64
VersionInfoProductName=Sacred 2
VersionInfoProductVersion=2.65.1
DiskSpanning=true
AppName=Sacred 2
AppVerName=2.65.1
PrivilegesRequired=none
DefaultDirName={pf}\Sacred 2
DirExistsWarning=yes
DefaultGroupName=Sacred 2
AlwaysShowDirOnReadyPage=true
AlwaysShowGroupOnReadyPage=true
ShowTasksTreeLines=false
AppPublisher=Deep Silver
AppVersion=2.65.1
AppID={{EE72C138-0DFC-4C17-9859-EBC5A8AF7517}
UninstallDisplayName=Sacred 2
[Icons]
Name: {group}\Sacred 2; Filename: {app}\system\sacred2.exe; WorkingDir: {app}; IconFilename: {app}\system\sacred2.exe; IconIndex: 0
Name: {commondesktop}\Sacred 2; Filename: {app}\system\sacred2.exe; WorkingDir: {app}; IconFilename: {app}\system\sacred2.exe; IconIndex: 0
Name: {group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,Sacred 2}; Filename: {uninstallexe}
```

Where is the bug? Thank you for help.
**Note:** The first .bin file have 2 099 610 368  the second have 2 100 000 000. Last file is small.

Comment: Just a sidenote (as this question seems to be unanswerable to me without clear reproduction of the problem); why are you using `DiskSpanning` ?

Comment: Because Inno will not work without this. In will say something like this "Installation file cannot be larger than 2 GB" This installation have about 14 GB. I have alot of memory and i have ran Memtest. I do not know where is the problem. I tested this on other computers and on one PC It was fine on the second PC it was with error. But same error was again and again. Other source have told me that it can be problem in compresion because my OC PC,  but i have tested my PC. It is fine. And one .bin file have different size? Error?

Comment: Maybe is problem with DiskPannig?

Answer (score 2):

I know what is causing the problem,it's `SolidCompression` which is causing the problem.

**How do I know that,because it already happened to me,and i solve this problem by reading some posts about `DiskSpanning` and compression in internet.**

U can use script like this one to get best compression inside inno-setup.Just change the name and files etc.

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{53C82ABA-56A0-4366-B4D3-7624CDDB2BA0}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=true
OutputBaseFilename=Setup
Compression=lzma/ultra64
SolidCompression=false
InternalCompressLevel=ultra64
DiskSpanning=True
DiskSliceSize=1566000000
SlicesPerDisk=3
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe

[Languages]
Name: english; MessagesFile: compiler:Default.isl

[Tasks]
Name: desktopicon; Description: {cm:CreateDesktopIcon}; GroupDescription: {cm:AdditionalIcons}; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg.exe; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: {group}\{#MyAppName}; Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}
Name: {group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}; Filename: {uninstallexe}
Name: {commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}; Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}; Tasks: desktopicon
```

**Note the `SolidCompression=false`**.

You can modify the size of Setup-*.bin by changeing this

```
[Setup]: DiskSliceSize
Valid values:
 262144 through 2100000000, or max  
Default value:
 max (2100000000)
```

**Description:This specifies the maximum number of bytes per disk slice (SETUP-*.BIN file). Normally, this should be set to the total number of bytes available on the disk media divided by the value of the SlicesPerDisk [Setup] section directive, which defaults to 1.**

**This directive is ignored if disk spanning is not enabled using the DiskSpanning [Setup] section directive.**

To optimally fill 4.7 GB recordable DVDs, use:

```
SlicesPerDisk=3
DiskSliceSize=1566000000
```

To optimally fill 8.5 GB (dual-layer) recordable DVDs, use:

```
SlicesPerDisk=5
DiskSliceSize=1708200000
```

To optimally fill 700 MB (80-minute) recordable CDs, use:

```
SlicesPerDisk=1
DiskSliceSize=736000000
```

To optimally fill 1.44MB floppy disks, use:

```
SlicesPerDisk=1
DiskSliceSize=1457664
```

(Taken from the inno setup documentation).